# How to increase the frame's width when the number of balls increases

Tags: html, css

[here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/momo0519/ybwe93x5/)

```
.containerSlave {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    height: 220px;
    /*item height x 10*/
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.containerSlave .ball {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 20px 15px, #7FBBFC, #000);
}
```

when the ball is under the status of limited height and automatically shift its longitudinal direction, how to make the balls to be covered within the frame. The frame will increase its width as the number of ball increase.

[image: Want to show the following]

Comment: This is a known issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882458/flex-box-container-width-doesnt-grow

Comment: Flex-Box has a number of known issues.
http://caniuse.com/#search=flex-box

It also needs a webkit prefix for use with Safari.

Answer (score 1):

OK I'm using Mozilla and this seems to work. This is your original code but I set width fixed in `containerSlave` to `75px`.

This would work and doesn't look bad but to be honest your going to need to use an outside code like JS (javascript). If you're open to that, I can show you a cool trick to fix it.

```
.containerSlave {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    height: 220px;

    **width:75px;**

    /*item height x 10*/
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.containerSlave .ball {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 20px 15px, #7FBBFC, #000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("containerSlave").style.width = s + "px";` with `s` being the new size in pizels (integer). You will need to add a `width` attribute to the CSS.

```
#containerSlave {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    height: 220px;
    /*item height x 10*/
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: <!-- yourwidth --> px
}
```

Note: Change the `<div class="containerSlave">` to `<div id="containerSlave">`

Comment: If you would like to show a live demo, please use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) instead of linking to your own site.